# Preload JS file or load images last

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a slider which uses bxslider as a plugin and the images load before the javascript therefore there is a moment before the JS file has loaded but before the images have where there is display issues. How can I fix this?

http://orchid-goose.cloudvent.net/

Comment: Is it possible to create a jsFiddle or inline code example? We tend to want avoid having questions that link to external sources in case those links go down.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341371/question-with-link-to-the-public-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set css property `visibility:hidden` for the slider and make it visible once the script has finished loading. You can have a placeholder image as background in the parent container, e.g. a gif indicating it is loading.

Comment: Awesome, how come this doesn't work. $(document).ready(function() { $('.hide').removeClass('.hide').addClass('.show'); });

Comment: Remove the `.` from the class name when calling `removeClass()` and `addClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

put the implementation of the slider in

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    // weave your magic here.
});
```

That function will be executed, when all data was loaded

Comment: Awesome, how come this doesn't work.

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide').removeClass('.hide').addClass('.show');
});

Comment: $(document).ready will be fired when the DOM is loaded
$(windows).on('loaded', () => {}) gets fired, when everything is loaded